# how can I pass an extra parameter to a controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this:

```
Route::get('/product/{id}', 'PagesController@display');
```

And in my PagesController I have this:

```
public function display($id) {
    return View::make("details", ["id" => $id, "premium" => $premium]);
}
```

How can I pass the variable `$premium` to the controller method **without inserting it in the url**? In simple words I don't want this: **www.mysite.com/product/false/125** (**false** is the value of `$premium`) but this: **www.mysite.com/product/125**. That's why I have just `$id` as parameter in the controller method and no also `$premium`. I want to pass that variable `$premium` in other way.

I've try some approaches like this one:

```
Route::get('/product/{id}', 'PagesController@display')->where("premium" => "false");
```

which didn't work.

Comment: @CodingCracker I thought I had been quit clear about it: "I don't want this: **www.mysite.com/product/false/125** (**false** is the value of $premium) but this: **www.mysite.com/product/125**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a closure route and call the action "manually":

```
Route::get('/product/{id}', function($id){
    return app('PagesController')->callAction('display', [$id, false]);
});
```

And

```
public function display($id, $premium) {
    return View::make("details", ["id" => $id, "premium" => $premium]);
}
```

Comment: I definetely am gonna use that approach. Thank you.

Comment: It's not showing up the **details.blade.php** page, just a blank page. I'm trying to figure out why. Any idea you or someone else may have just let me know.

Comment: Body you forgot to ``return`` something in the ``route::get`` and drove me crazy with that for a little while before noticing. Add the ``return`` to the answer to accept it. :)

Comment: Well it looks like we commented at the same time. I'm gonna accept your answer just make sure to edit it. thank you!